# Parsing the json data from google and twitter differences

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I am new to javascript. I have worked on twitter API. In twitter API i used jQuery.ajax function to get json data from twitter servers. But when i use the same option with google maps server, my app isn't giving any response the moment it enters the jQuery.ajax. I tried to debug it using jslint, but it came out clean. I used debugging using alert, and it stops when it enters jQuery.ajax function. Is meathod to retrieve data varies with the source ?
If not why isn't my code responding ?

Twitter running function   ::

```
 var twitterapi = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?";
          jQuery.ajax(
          {
             type: "GET",
             url: twitterapi,
             data: 
              {
                "q": hashtag,
                 "rpp": 1000
              },
              dataType: 'jsonp'
          }).done(function (response) 
             {
                var results = response.results;
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
                 {

                    $("#tweet").prepend("<li class='tweet'>" +
                    "<img src='" + 
                    results[i].profile_image_url + 
                    "'/>" + 
                    "<span class='username'>" +
                    results[i].from_user +
                    "</span> <span class='tweet_content'> " +
                    results[i].text + 
                    "</span></li>");
                  }
              });
```

My google maps API(not working)

```
    var j = 2;
var friends = [];
var distance =[];

$(document).ready(function () {

     alert("function started");
    $('#button').click(function () {
        if (j < 11) {
            $('#friends').append('Friend' + j + ':<input type="text" id="friend' + j + '"/><br/><br/>');
            j++;
        }
        else {
            alert("Limit reached");
        }
    });



   $('button').click(function(){
   var a =[];
   alert("button clickede");
    for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
     {
        a[i] = $("#friend" + i).val();
      }     


    var gurl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?"+
        "origins=" +
        a.join('|').replace(/ /g,'+') +
        "&destinations=" +
        a.join('|').replace(/ /g,'+') +
        "&sensor=false";

           alert("making request to" +gurl);
            jQuery.ajax(
          {
             type: "GET",
             url: gurl,
             dataType: 'jsonp'
          }).done(function (response) 
           {
           alert("request made to"+gurl);

           var rows = response.rows;        
             alert(row[0].elements[0].value);

       for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
         {
             for(var j=0;j<elements.length;j++)
              {
                       distance[i][j] = row[i].elements[j].distance.value;
              } 
          }


            alert(distance[0][0]);
        }); 

     });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what error are you getting so i can't be of much help.

But the code you posted has three issues:

1- Since a is undefined, i couldn't get past the first two lines.

2- Removing the a calls in the code, then it threw a Syntax Error. I fixed this by removing the last }); line.

3- It made the request, but it threw another error (probably because the URL was malformed).

Comment: i have posted just a part of my code. I have declared a, the last }); is also OK. and the url it request works!